# How it happened that in cactuses the difference between the fruit, the leaf and the stem so much blurred if they were normal plants in the past?

Tags: evolution, botany

Looking at a cactus may make impression that they evolved separately from other plants, which usually have stem, leaf and fruit.

But the fruit in cactuses has the same structure and surface as the leaf and stem, and grows from leaves. How this could come? Cacti are flowering plants, so should had evolved from normal plants.
[image]

Comment: cactus have stem leaves and fruit, the needles are modified leaves, the big flat green parts are the stem.

Comment: It makes sense if you think of it in terms of water conservation.  Cacti are adapted to environments where there's plentiful sunlight, so growth is limited by water.